# writing and reading file with date in the name

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, filereader

I am trying to write a file in java with the current date and time appended in the name of the file and then I want to read the same file after writing it but the date and time is changed and it cannot find the file.

This is what I have tried

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss" );
```

Write the file:

```
File messagesFile = new File(dirName + "\\2g3gPS_Messages_Statistics_" +
  df.format(new Date() ) + ".csv");
if (!messagesFile.exists()) {
  messagesFile.createNewFile();
}
```

Read the file:

```
records = reader.readData(dirName2G3GPS + "\\\\2g3gPS_Messages_Statistics_" +
  df.format(new Date() ) + ".csv");
```

let suppose I write the file at 10:54:10 and I try to read it at 10:54:50 then it will not find the file.

How can I read the latest file written in the directory. Is there any other work aorund?

Comment: Use the same instance of `Date`, don't create a new one.

Comment: Store the date in a variable so you can use these date by reeading and writing, or genereate the filename once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `new Date()` which will give the time when it is called - different for writing and reading.

Instead call `Date date = new Date()` and use this `date` at both the places

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should keep track of your `new Date()` value that you used to write a file to read the file again later.

If you always want to read the latest file from the given directory, you could sort the filenames and read the last one.
Something like this could help:

```
File dir = new File(dirName);
String[] filenames = dir.list();
Arrays.sort(filenames);
File latestFile = new File(dir.getParentFile(), filenames[filenames.length - 1]);
```

Of course, this solution works under the assumption that all files within the `dirName` directory have same filename format.

Answer (score 0):

Get the directory listing and use Calendar or [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to compare the parsed file name times.